# What is the advantage of linking to Firebase project in Google Analytics if legacy data will be unavailable after October 2019?

Tags: firebase, google-analytics

What is the advantage of linking to Firebase project in Google Analytics as explained [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2587086?hl=en) if legacy data will be unavailable after October 2019? As per Google's communication, it seems it is up to developers to ensue they have taken backups of legacy analytics data, so how does the integration process explained in this article help or why is it needed?

Thanks
Padmanabhan

Answer (score 0):

The sunset is not for Firebase properties, but for Google Analytics mobile. So Firebase properties linked in GA won't be affected at all.

When you link GA and Firebase, it is really just another way for you to just access to analytics data in Firebase.

Comment: Hi XTOTHEL, you have mentioned analytics data in Firebase, do you mean legacy Google Analytics data? Can you kindly explain detail?